# Migrating from Google calendar V3 (1.5.0.56-beta) version to latest Dlls i.e Version 3(1.8.1.820)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am using Google calendar version 3(1.5.0.56-beta) beta for my asp.net application, now I want to upgrade these DLL to version 3(1.8.1.820). I have downloaded the new DLLs but not it is showing that NativeApplicationClient, GoogleAuthenticationServer are not in these DLLs. Please check the below code that I am using for V3 beta version

```
private CalendarService CreateService(string token)
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string> credentials = Common.Get3LOCredentials();
    var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
    provider.ClientIdentifier = credentials.Key;
    provider.ClientSecret = credentials.Value;
    var auth = new Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, (p) => GetAuthorization(provider, token, credentials.Key, credentials.Value));
    CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        Authenticator = auth,
        ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIkey"].ToString(),
        GZipEnabled = false
    });
    provider = null;
    return service;
}
 private IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg, String Refreshtoken, string clientid, string clientsecret)
{
    int retrycount = 0;
    IAuthorizationState state = null;
    string accesstoken = string.Empty;

    while (retrycount < 7)
    {
        accesstoken = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue() });
            state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);// NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);                
            ProfileSettingsBL bl = BLFactory.CurrentInstance.ProfileSettingsBLObj;
            ProfileSettingsDS.SOUserCalendarAccountRow row = bl.RetrieveSOUserCalendarAccountByToken(Refreshtoken);
            if (row != null)
            {
                string[] splitter = new string[1];
                splitter[0] = Constants.EQUAL_REPLACE_STRING;
                string[] arr = row.Token.Split(splitter, StringSplitOptions.None);
                if (arr.Length == 1)
                {
                    accesstoken = ExchangeCodeWithAccessAndRefreshToken(Refreshtoken, clientid, clientsecret, retrycount);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accesstoken))
                    {
                        string[] arr1 = accesstoken.Split(splitter, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        if (arr1.Length > 1)
                        {
                            bl.updateAccessToken(Refreshtoken, arr1[0], arr1[1]);
                            accesstoken = arr1[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (arr.Length >= 1)
                        accesstoken = arr[1];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string[] splitter = new string[1];
                splitter[0] = Constants.EQUAL_REPLACE_STRING;
                accesstoken = ExchangeCodeWithAccessAndRefreshToken(Refreshtoken, clientid, clientsecret, retrycount);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accesstoken))
                {
                    string[] arr1 = accesstoken.Split(splitter, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    if (arr1.Length >= 1)
                        accesstoken = arr1[0];
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accesstoken))
                state.AccessToken = accesstoken;
            state.RefreshToken = Refreshtoken;               
            return state;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

can anyone please help me in this regards, unable to find good documentation for .NET developers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have converted the old application to new one, here you just need to use UserCredential class that is inside the Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2. Kindly check the below code for this.

```
private CalendarService CreateService(string token)
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string> credentials = Common.Get3LOCredentials();
    String AccessToken = GetAuthorization(RefreshToken, credentials.Key, credentials.Value);
    var tokenCode = new TokenResponse() { RefreshToken = RefreshToken, AccessToken = AccessToken };
    var secreat = new ClientSecrets() { ClientId = credentials.Key, ClientSecret = credentials.Value };
    UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        ClientSecrets = secreat
    }), "user", tokenCode);
    var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API Sample",
    });
    return service;
}
```

It is really very easy than before code that Google was having in Beta versions.